# Error occurred while starting debugger for ASP.NET Core application on VS2015.3

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am teaching myself how to build websites using asp.net core/mvc6. For the same, I installed VS2015 update 3 community edition. I have extensive background with C# and .NET Framework, but not much with web applications

I am just trying to create a simple project and start debugging, but the debug mostly (say 90% times) fails with the below message

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id if the
>   {APPLICATION} which is hosting your application

**You can reproduce my issue by following the below steps:**

1. Create a new "ASP.NET CORE" application in visual studio, using default selections
   [image: NewProject]
   [image: ProjectTemplate]
2. Build the project successfully without errors or warnings
3. Click the "Start Debugging" button
   [image: DebugRun]
4. I get the "Debug is starting" progressbar, 
   [image: DebugStarting]
5. After that it mostly fails but sometimes succeeds in starting the debug session. When it fails, I get the below message.
   [image: DebugFailed]
6. When it succeeds I first get a dialog complaining about 64 bit debugging and then the debug session starts fine.
   [image: DebugSlowness]

**I have tried the below with no luck**

1. I can run fine the website through Visual Studio without debugging.
2. I can also debug and run fine a .NET core console application from within VS.
3. I have `Avira (antivirus)` and `ZoneAlarm (Firewall)` installed on the machine where I am trying all this. I have tried exiting ZoneAlarm and stopping real-time protection on Avira and set my `UAC` to not prompt, and then try debugging, but no luck. I cannot uninstall those items for trying.
4. I have tried repairing VS2015.3. I have also tried uninstalling and installing cleanly VS2015.3.
5. If I follow the below steps, the debugger starts fine (sometimes with the 64 bit debugging warning). I am sure that attaching the debugger to the running website would also work fine:

   - Start Debugging using F5
   - Right click IIS Express and browse to the application quickly
     [image: IISExpress]
6. The debug works fine, if I use the kestrel web-server
7. I have tried using ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 and 1.1.0.
8. Using IE instead of Chrome did not make any difference
9. I even tried using VS 2017 RC2

I would like to be able to debug without any "hacks" and also, get rid of the 64 bit slowness complains

Comment: Reproduce it with Process Monitor and check the log. It can give you some answers and a lot of questions (probably) too...

Comment: I had already tried that but with not much luck. There were too many messages even after reasonably filtering the output. Nothing really stood-out. My feeling is that the Firewall or my antivirus is interfering. Uninstalling them cleanly is a lot more laborious (and lot more potential to screw up my system) so trying to avoid that.

Comment: maybe try in checking if the problem exists in a virtual machine?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I don't really have any VM to try this out.

Comment: @ Vikhram, what is your project's platform target "X86/x64/Any CPU"? If you use the default "Any CPU", how about the result? I also suggest you close the Firewall or antivirus, test it again. If you couldn't close the firewall, just a suggestion: Allow certain Programs like VS debugging/remote debugging through the Firewall, check it again.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my VS2015.3 (version 14.0.25431.01) based on your steps and successful no matter how many times I debug it.

Please check your .NET Core version to make sure it is the latest version first. The latest version should be NET Core 1.0.3. You could get it from this link: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

And according to the message when you could successful debugging, your are using some 3rd party networking software. So please make sure you **closed all other programs** when debugging.

In addition, I found you are debugging using Chrome. Please choose Internet Explorer to confirm whether this issue related to the Chrome.

Comment: I have tried on 1.0.1 and currently on 1.1.0. To the same effect. I had also tried with IE; still the same result. I even tried using VS 2017 RC2; still no luck. Also while debugging, I have my chrome and VS up. Other than that the AV and Firewall are the other software I have my doubts on, but couldn't find any prrof to blame them yet

Comment: Do you use network proxy when using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: no, I am directly connected to the internet without any intermediate proxy

Comment: Please try exist the AV and Firewall to check whether one of them causes this issue. And if possible, please debug on another machine without any third part software installed to confirm this issue related to machine environment or not.